# actionscript 3 Timer class and callback problems

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I have a timer class in actionscript that looks like this:

```
        public class AGTimer {

                    public var myTimer:Timer ;
                    public var done:Boolean = false;
                    public var timer_disable:Boolean = false;
                    public var started:Boolean = false;

            public function AGTimer(num:Number = 0) {
                    this.timer_disable = false;
                    if (num != 0 ) timerStart(num);
                    // constructor code

            }
            public function timerStart(num:Number):void {

                    myTimer = new Timer(num * 1000, 1);
                    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, runOnce);
                    myTimer.start();
                    started = true;
                    done = false;
            }

            public function runOnce(e:TimerEvent):void {
                    done = true;
            }

            public function timerDone():Boolean {

                    if (done && ! timer_disable) return true;
                    else if (!started ) return true;
                    else return false;
            }
    }
```

I have several of these in an array. I reference them with their index number. sometimes I start a timer and let it go, then before I have a chance to check it, I delete it by calling 'new AGTimer()' and creating a new one. Could it happen that the callback from the actionscript Timer object is still called somehow after the timer itself is deleted? What would I do about it if it did happen? I am trying to find a bug and am considering this sort of problem. What kind of error would I see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a timer will continue to run callbacks even if it is not referenced somewhere. You have to remove event listener for the timer for it in order to remove it.

Basically something like this:

```
private function destroyTimer():void {
    if(myTimer) {
        myTimer.removeEventListener(runOnce);
        myTimer.stop();
        myTimer = null;
    }
}
```